# Wordpress Plugin Error - jQuery is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm using a WP plugin which enqueues a js file. Today I saw a the following error in the console

```
jquery is not defined...
```

After deactivating the plugin and activating it again the error is gone. Usually “jQuery is not defined” is a sign jQuery is being called incorrectly. I checked the code and can't find any error. Any idea how to avoid this kind of error or is there any error in the following code?

```
function bb_qv_enqueue_scripts(){
wp_enqueue_script('bb-qv-js',plugins_url('/assets/js/bb-qv-js.js',__FILE__),array('jquery'),'1.7',true);
wp_localize_script('bb-qv-js','bb_qv_localize',array(
    'adminurl' => admin_url().'admin-ajax.php'
    ));
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','bb_qv_enqueue_scripts');
```

Comment: you  have added Jquery  library file >

Comment: There is no problem with the Wordpress jQuery library files or so - just with the plugin... (i hope this was the point of you)

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to be on the jQuery plugin since you are already specifying through wp_enqueue_script that the file requires jquery. This could be many things, maybe it's conflicting with some other library.

Try to declare a new alias for jQuery at the beginning of your file and then replace all jQuery or $ with the new alias. Something like this:

```
var newAlias = jQuery.noConflict();
newAlias(document).ready(function()...
```